# Stored Procedure in H2 Database for selecting data

Tags: sql-server, database

Please help me to write a stored procedure for an H2 database to bind a cursor and loop through it to fetch the data

Also, can I run MS-SQL stored procedure in H2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MS-SQL has MS specific TSQL language features that are none standard. If your stored proc uses any of these, it will unlikely work in H2.